# Microsoft Vision API image preprocessing

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, vision-api

Does anybody know if Microsoft Vision API performs any image optimisation (further than angle corrections) to improve image quality such as perspective correction, image enhancement, greyscale conversion...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it do image optimisation by just scaling down the quality. It does not enhance the image quality

**scaling down the size doesn't mean improving the quality and correcting the image visibility**

Microsoft Vision API's are specially made to recognise an object, As they mentioned in their document. There is no special editing in image which user tried to upload for recognition. Before uploading an image for cognitive service, Cognitive services just restrict the image size being above 2MB.

[Please refer the image size reducing class from microsoft cognitive services](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android/blob/master/Sample/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/visionsample/helper/ImageHelper.java)

This class just correct the image as per the cognitive needs. Does not improve the quality and does not enhance the image visibility